# How to implement a Modeling Application with GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, modeling

I'm trying to implement a application with GUI in Java that can let users build a model using certain predefined modeling language.

Is there any approach that I could easily build a GUI where user can do "drag a circle into canvas", "connect this circle with that rectangle", etc?

Or I should just use Swing.(maybe Swing Builder for simplicity). listen to the action of mouse and draw something accordingly?

Also I found Graphic Modeling Frame work in Eclipse very interesting, but I'm not sure if I could integrate it into my App easily.

Comment: The choice is yours, you need to evaluate each potential to see if it meets your needs or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would give the Eclipse Modeling Framework a try before starting to write something in Swing (or SwingBuilder - you mean the Swing framework for Groovy?), unless you need something very simple and you are quite sure the required functionality will remain small.

According to the FAQ on the [Eclipse wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/FAQ#I_want_to_use_EMF.2C_SDO.2C_or_XSD_in_my_standalone_project.2C_or_include_only_a_working_subset_of_the_code._What_libraries_.28jar_files.29_do_I_need_in_my_CLASSPATH.3F), it is possible to use EMF standalone in your application:

> "I want to use EMF, SDO, or XSD in my standalone project, or include only a working subset of the code. What libraries (jar files) do I need in my CLASSPATH?
>
> Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF) provides the infrastructure to run the generated models and dynamic model based on existing ecore files. It also provides XMI/XML serialization and deserialization.
>
> The following jars can be used in standalone mode. [Lists of jars are provided for several scenarios.]"

This [EMF tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html) by Lars Vogel could also be useful.

Comment: Thank you ! I will check it out.